# Calculating sum of ARCH coefficients

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, analytics

Hi I am in need of some help with R code results.

I am trying to calculate the sum of the ARCH and GARCH coefficients?

I used to following code to build my model:

`msft.log.m1 <- garchFit(~1 + garch(5, 0), data = returns$MSFT, trace = F)
summary(msft.log.m1)`

and got this in return:

Coefficient(s):
        mu       omega      alpha1      alpha2      alpha3      alpha4      alpha5
0.00034583  0.00010584  0.15897896  0.19006924  0.14060682  0.14418461  0.20332370

along with a bunch of other results. Am I supposed to add these up to get the sum? or am I completely off base with what the question is asking?

Any guidance would be great, thank you!

Comment: with `str()` u will see how to extract the coefficients and if you have extracted the array, you simply use `sum()` on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `fGarch::garchFit()` vignette or the `fGarch` package details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/fGarch.pdf)

As your model fit is an S4 object you will need to pull the model fit coefficients using `msft.log.m1@fit` (see page 13).

BigDataScientist suggests using `str(msft.log.m1)` to determine which slots are available to retrieve in console.